# Iterate over two Data Frames and Find the matching value in second data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframes with 2 columns in each(columns are fixed), i want to perform some operation on those data frame row,columns if i would not find similar entry for data frame one of row in data frame two of any rows. For example my Data Frames are as follows:
'''

```
df1:                           
KEY    VALUE 
age    24 
edu    PUC 
id     123 
job_c  student 

df2: 
KEY  VALUE 
age  24 
edu  BSc 
id   123 
sal  10K 
job  accountant
```

here there is

- change in 'edu' row value of df2 compared to df1 'edu'.
- 'sal' row is newly added in df2 which is not available in df1.
- df1 row 'job_c' has been changed to 'job' in df2.

I want to iterate over these two dataframes and wherever there is a change in row/column, i have to perform specific operations over those row/column and push back to the respective dataframes.

I tried with df.iterrows(), tried with isin df compare, also with the below links, which is not solving my problem.
[Pandas: How could I iterate two dataframes which have exactly same format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709557/pandas-how-could-i-iterate-two-dataframes-which-have-exactly-same-format)

Please help me on this case... Thanks in advance.
Note: there is no primary or unique key relationship here ..

Expected Output would be:

```
df1:                           
KEY                       VALUE 
age                       24 
edu                       <color=Red>PUC</color> 
id                        123 
job<color=Red>_c</color>  <color=Red>student</color> 

df2: 
KEY                        VALUE 
age                        24 
edu                        <color=green>BSc</color> 
id                         123 
<color=green>sal</color>   <color=green>10K</color>  
job                        <color=green>accountant</color>
```

Comment: May you exemplify explicitly what the desired output is? The actual solution depends on what you'd like to perform.

Comment: @BillHuang i have edited my post with expected output, thanks

Comment: What is the rule of name change in "KEY"? Does it always involve removing a suffix? If the matching rule is not clear, then the answerer may not be able to implement that.

Comment: Assume there is a column named `A1_A2` in `df1`, and columns named  `A1` and `A2` in `df2`. Which column should be identified as a match in `df2`, `A1` or `A2`?

Comment: In this case '''A1_A2''' becomes the old entry to the '''df1''' so we need to change it as <color=Red>A1_A2</color> . and '''A1''' & '''A2''' becomes new entry/new column to the '''df2''' so in df2 we have to update it as <color=green>A1</color> , <color=green>A2</color>

Comment: If there are keys `job_c`, `job_f`, `edu_job` in `df1` and a key `job` in `df2`, which one do you mark as red? All three of them? And which value are you going to compare with?

Comment: There are too many potential anomalies that we cannot see from the given example. You may have to better describe what your data actually looks like. Otherwise anything would be possible.

Comment: Here there is no relationship between Key and Value columns, anything changes either its in key or its in value or its only a key/value i want to color it. I just want to compare each element of df1 with the respective element position in df2.                   "job_c", "job_f", "edu_job" have to be mark as red and "job" to be colored as green.